# getting Tycho to resolve dependencies from old-style Eclipse update site

Tags: maven, eclipse-plugin, tycho

I'm trying to build a plugin that depends on `org.apache.uima.runtime`, which is part of the [UIMA Eclipse plugins](http://uima.apache.org/d/uimaj-2.4.0/overview_and_setup.html#ugr.ovv.eclipse_setup) hosted on the [UIMA Eclipse update site](http://www.apache.org/dist/uima/eclipse-update-site/). This update site is an old-style (pre-p2) update site, so I know that [Tycho won't resolve those dependencies](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=380438). So I'm trying to make a local copy of the UIMA Eclipse update site, upgrade it to p2, and then get the dependencies from there. Here's what I tried:

```
$ svn co http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/uima/uimaj/trunk/uimaj-eclipse-update-site/
...
Checked out revision 1395335.

$ java -jar /.../eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar \
  -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.UpdateSitePublisher \
  -metadataRepository file:/.../uimaj-eclipse-update-site \
  -artifactRepository file:/.../uimaj-eclipse-update-site \
  -source /.../uimaj-eclipse-update-site
Generating metadata for ..
Generation completed with success [0 seconds].
```

If I look at the `uimaj-eclipse-update-site` directory, I now see an `artifacts.xml` and a `content.xml`, so that seems right. I also checked it with the [p2 repository browser](https://github.com/ifedorenko/p2-browser), and nothing shows up as "PARTIAL", and I can see an `org.apache.uima.runtime.feature.jar 2.4.0` and an `org.apache.uima.runtime.feature.group 2.4.0`.

I now add this local site to the pom.xml of my Eclipse plugin:

```
<repository>
    <id>uima</id>
    <layout>p2</layout>
    <url>file:/.../uimaj-eclipse-update-site</url>
</repository>
```

When I run `mvn compile` in my updated project, Tycho finds the local update site, but still can't find `org.apache.uima.runtime`:

```
...
[INFO] Adding repository file:/.../uimaj-eclipse-update-site
[INFO] Adding repository file:/.../uimaj-eclipse-update-site
[INFO] Resolving dependencies of MavenProject: org.cleartk:org.cleartk.plugin.jcasgen.m2e:0.9.1.qualifier @ /.../jcasgen-m2e-connector/org.cleartk.plugin.jcasgen.m2e/pom.xml
[INFO] Cannot complete the request.  Generating details.
[INFO] Cannot complete the request.  Generating details.
[INFO] {osgi.ws=cocoa, osgi.os=macosx, osgi.arch=x86_64, org.eclipse.update.install.features=true}
[ERROR] Cannot resolve project dependencies:
[ERROR]   Software being installed: org.cleartk.plugin.jcasgen.m2e 0.9.1.qualifier
[ERROR]   Missing requirement: org.cleartk.plugin.jcasgen.m2e 0.9.1.qualifier requires 'bundle org.apache.uima.runtime [2.4.0,3.0.0)' but it could not be found
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Internal error: java.lang.RuntimeException: "No solution found because the problem is unsatisfiable."
...
```

What am I doing wrong?

If you want to replicate the error, I'm running `mvn compile` from this directory (after modifying the pom.xml as above):

http://cleartk.googlecode.com/git/jcasgen-m2e-connector/

**EDIT:** I do see `org.apache.uima.runtime` in the generated `artifacts.xml`:

```
<artifact classifier='org.eclipse.update.feature' id='org.apache.uima.runtime' version='2.4.0'>
  <properties size='4'>
    <property name='artifact.size' value='9466'/>
    <property name='download.size' value='9466'/>
    <property name='download.md5' value='f9d4f1f8dc54f0a99379dcede2fc2700'/>
    <property name='download.contentType' value='application/zip'/>
  </properties>
</artifact>
```

Comment: Your approach looks good in principal, I can't see an obvious error. Is the missing really contained in your converted p2 repository?

Comment: I believe so. I've added a snippet above of the artifacts.xml where I see what looks like the `org.apache.uima.runtime` that I'm looking for.

Comment: That snippet looks to be the org.apache.uima.runtime feature rather than the org.apache.uima.runtime plugin. Browsing the svn repo link, it looks like the plugins directory is empty and there are only features present. However the update site URL does have plugins in it's plugins directory. Can you check that your local plugins directory has some plugins? You may instead need to mirror the remote repository then run the FeaturesAndBundlesPublisher application.

Comment: Looking at your svn repository, you may just need to run maven first to "build" it.

Comment: Only the `content.xml` is used for dependency resolution; the `artifacts.xml` only becomes relevant after dependency resolution.

Comment: @Simon: That was exactly it! The svn repo has the features built, but not the plugins. Once I fixed a bug in their pom.xml and ran `mvn process-sources`, I got a `target/eclipse-update-site` where I could run the FeaturesAndBundlesPublisher. Could you add something about the missing plugins directory to your answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Browsing the svn repo link, it looks like the plugins directory is empty and there are only features present. You may just need to run maven first to "build" it and populate the plug-ins directory.

If you have all of the content you could run the [p2 features and bundles publisher](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox/p2/Publisher#Features_and_Bundles_Publisher_Application) application to generate a p2 repository directly. If it is to be consumed in a Tycho build the category side of the update site does not need to be generated.

Comment: +1 UpdateSitePublisher will not create complete p2 metadata but FeaturesAndBundlesPublisher will

Comment: So I just tried FeaturesAndBundlesPublisher instead of UpdateSitePublisher and the error is the same.

Comment: And just to confirm, after getting their update site to build, UpdateSitePublisher did not generate all the necessary metadata, but FeaturesAndBundlesPublisher did.

Answer (score 1):

I got late to the party but Apache UIMA now has a p2 repository.

In your pom.xml add the uima repository:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>uima</id>
        <url>http://www.apache.org/dist/uima/eclipse-update-site</url>
        <layout>p2</layout>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```